# Grunt watch plugin does not display UglifyJS abort message

Tags: node.js, build-automation, gruntjs

grunt-contrib-watch plugin provides nice auto-build feature but in some occasions does not display warning message from tasks, here is my grunt.js:

```
    min: {
        app: {
            src: [
                'some.js',
            ],
            dest: 'some.min.js'
        },
    }

    watch: {
        app: {
            files: 'some.js',
            tasks: ['min:app']
        },
    }
```

if source is fine, that everything goes smoothly; however when UglifyJS aborts:

run grunt min:app directly

```
Running "min:app" (min) task
Minifying with UglifyJS...ERROR
[L360:C46] Unexpected token name, expected punc (position: 8529)
<WARN> UglifyJS found errors. Use --force to continue. </WARN>

Aborted due to warnings.
```

auto-build via watch plugin

```
Waiting...OK
>> File "some.js" changed.
Running "min:app" (min) task
```

so there is no way to know if build is successful without looking at output itself.

similar setup with css less does display error to CLI, I am wondering if there is something I need to pass to grunt/watch plugin/uglify to makes it work?

Comment: are you getting errors at the same position while running grunt watch?

Comment: Not sure if I get your question: the problem is grunt watch does not tell me whether there is an error. Both error/success result in the same message I quoted above (3rd quote). only manually run grunt min task will display the error - I can certainly fix it then, but it defeats the purpose of watch plugin.

Comment: sorry, just misunderstood your question.  To clarify, watch doesn't do your auto-build, Uglify does.  Watch is just a development tool.

Comment: you are right, I am just trying to understand why watch does not pipe the error message from uglify to cli.

Comment: uglify should only pipe errors to cli during the build phase, which you would init by running `grunt min` in cli.  you should be running `grunt watch` during development, and it will continuously monitor watched files and pipe errors (or successes after saves) to your cli.  However, the way you have watch configured, all running watch does is run uglify, which is your build tool, which defeats the purpose of watch.  I would remove the min command from the watch config entirely.

Comment: hmmm, did I misunderstand the config doc? because I have another watch like: `css: { files: 'less/*.less', tasks: ['less'] }`, it does do what you described, build on save and pipe error/success message just fine. To me the less task is the same as min task - both a multi-task.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24812/discussion-between-brian-vanderbusch-and-bitinn)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like Grunt v0.3.x + grunt-contrib-watch v0.1.4 is indeed the problem...

https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch/issues/19

https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch/issues/7

(**EDIT**: after upgrading to Grunt v0.4.x + grunt-contrib-watch v0.2.x, issue is resolved; though I should note this is a breaking upgrade, most v0.3 plugins are not converted to support Grunt v0.4 yet)

I closed my ticket on their repo as well, for reference: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch/issues/51

Comment: despite the downvote, I am still going to mark this as my answer, because the issue is clearly there (my config is correct). If you got a better answer, go ahead and report back to the github issue.

Answer (score 0):

Watch used jshint, and you need to make sure jshint is configured properly, then added to your grunt tasks for the watch command.  Add the jshint task to your watch tasks, and also include a config options for jshint (example below):

```
 jshint: {
   all: [
    'Gruntfile.js',
    'some.js'
  ],
  options: {
    jshintrc: '.jshintrc'
  }
},
// minification options here
watch: {
  scripts: {
    files: 'some.js',
    tasks: ['jshint']

 }
}
```

Comment: I think jshint is just another contrib plugin? min is a built-in multi task for v0.3, I assume it works with watch plugin just like css LESS task (which works)..

Comment: i know when I use grunt watch, I configure jshint, and I don't contrib it in, configuring it somewhat similar to above.  This comes directly from the contrib-watch docs on github: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch/blob/master/Gruntfile.js, every example I've ever seen grunt watch ran, it was configured using jshint